# Responsive Image with Max-height & Max-width

Tags: html, css

I have this html and CSS

```
<div class="kalim"><img  src=""></div>
```

CSS

```
.kalim {display: inline-block;}

.kalim img {max-width: 800px;width: auto;max-height: 800px;}
```

The problem with this code is that the images are not responsive in width when the browser is resized. If I set `width:100%` then the portrait images exceeding 800px in height become distorted.

Is there a workaround for this, to make the image responsive and also have the max-height and max-width settings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should add the width restriction to the outer element instead of the image. The outer element will not size over your max-width and max-height, but the image will always be 100% in width. This way your image will be responsive.

html

```
 <div class="kalim"><img src=""></div>
```

css

```
.kalim {display: inline-block; max-width: 800px; max-height: 800px;}

.kalim img {max-width: 100%; height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use object-fit to make the answer simpler:

```css
.kalim img {max-width: 800px; max-height: 800px; object-fit: contain;}
```

or

```css
.kalim img {max-width: 800px; max-height: 800px; object-fit: cover;}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score 1):

Like the bootstrap class css of img-responsive or img-fluid bs4

```
<img src="chicago.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: 800px"/>
```

Comment: but I also need to keep max-width:800px - this solution does not account for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, you can add the class `img-fluid` and set `width` and `height` properties.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x1600" width="800" height="800">
```

As you can the the size of the image is 1600x1600 but it will not exceed the size of 800x800 in the webpage. Also this is responsive.

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x1600" width="800" height="800" alt="Image from unsplash">

</html>
```