# Responsive site's initial viewport zoom is incorrect on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My responsive site's initial zoom is incorrect on mobile:

[image]

Sample HTML is below (and in this live [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/hgj42h3/pen/NQqVwp)).

You can see that I'm already using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .ctaGrabber{
                word-wrap: break-word;
                font-size: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding-left: 30px !important;
                padding-right: 30px !important;
                padding-top: 20px !important;
                padding-bottom: 20px !important;              
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <div class="container mainContainer hideWhenShowingForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1>“Here is a great title about a whole bunch of cool stuff”</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center presenters">            
                    left col
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary ctaGrabber" data-hiddenForm="#hiddenCrmForm">
                            <span>YES! Watch The Training Now!</span>
        <!--                    <span class="elButtonSub" style="font-size: 14px; display: block;"></span>-->
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Why does my `a.ctaGrabber` button's font-size not cause the mobile "zoom" to be wider?**

How can I either force the viewport zoom factor to honor this large font-size OR wrap the button text (without me specifying a button width)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, I figured it out:

**I needed to add `white-space: normal;` to my `.ctaGrabber` style** to override the `white-space: nowrap;` style of `.btn` in Bootstrap's `buttons.less` file.

**Update:**

The way to narrow down what element is causing the horizontal scroll bar is to use the Inspect panel and remove elements one at a time.

Then, once you’ve figured out the offending element, remove/edit one CSS property at a time.

In my case just recently, I found that an `img` was using the Bootstrap `img-responsive` class but also had `max-width: 450px;`, which overrode Bootstrap's `max-width: 100%;`. The solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194061/470749) was to wrap the `img` in a `div` with this class:

```
.imgMaxWidthWrapper{
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}
```